# On Ubuntu which version of docker need to used?

Tags: 14.04, docker

I need to use docker from ubuntu having confusion which version of docker to be installed docker.io or docker,and also i need to TCP that docker url for jenkins docker-agent.

So to TCP a docker ubuntu machine which is best option?

Answer (score 1):

The package `docker` contains a "System tray for KDE3/GNOME2 docklet applications" and is not related to docker containers. You need to install the package `docker.io`.